# Downloading this blip.tv video

Tags: video-download, blip.tv

How do I download the video corresponding to the following [blip.tv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blip.tv) URL? It should be accomplished without the need to install extra software and preferably without requiring JavaScript.

```
http://blip.tv/play/AYGTjRwC
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the [direct link](http://blip.tv/file/get/Mustardseedhd-OrganicGroupsBasics654.m4v) to the file (91.1 MB). Right click and select "save as" to download it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. How did you find that download URL?

Comment: I'm using an extra software called Stream Transport.